# How to convert a json value "aaa,bbb" to a "Seq[String]" with argonaut?

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

I'm using argonaut to parse json to case classes.

Json:

```
{
    "name" : "Mike",
    "email" : "a@aaa.com, b@bbb.com"
}
```

Scala:

```
case class User(agentName: String, emails: Seq[String])

object User {
  implicit def DecodeJson: DecodeJson[User] =
    casecodec2(User.apply, User.unapply)("name", "email")
}
```

The code can't be compiled, the error is:

```
Error:(17, 65) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type        
    argonaut.EncodeJson[Seq[String]]
    casecodec2(User.apply, User.unapply)("name", "email")
```

How to fix it so I can parse `a@aaa.com, b@bbb.com` to a `Seq("a@aaa.com", "b@bbb.com")`?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `casecodec2` are functions, so if you need to perform an operation like this on the parsed JSON you can do it there:

```
case class User(agentName: String, emails: Seq[String])

object User {
  implicit val CodecJson: CodecJson[User] = casecodec2[String, String, User](
    (n, e) => User(n, e.split(", ")),
    u => Some((u.agentName, u.emails.mkString(", ")))
  )("name", "email")
}
```

Or, if you really only need the decoder:

```
object User {
  implicit def DecodeJson: DecodeJson[User] =
    jdecode2L((n: String, e: String) => User(n, e.split(", ")))("name", "email")
}
```

`casecodecN` is made for convenient use with case class constructors and extractors, but it's much more flexible than just that.